# Datatable Select returning Array Index out of bounds

Tags: c#, silverlight

This line:

```
searchParamsTable.Select(string.Format("TABLE = {0} AND FIELD = '{1}'", tableNumbers[i], fieldName[i]))[0]["VALUE"] = wildcardedSearchString;
```

returns an Array Index out of bounds exception in C#. How can I write this to not throw the error? Or is there an alternate way I can write this if no records are returned to continue execution of the code? I search through three different tables for result using line with 'i' as the increment of the table and field names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is incomplete, how should we know what `tableNumbers`,`fieldName` and `wildcardedSearchString` are? The exception is probably thrown at tableNumbers[i], fieldName[i] or the `[0]` indexer of the select.

I assume that the select doesn't return rows, so `[0]` will throw an  `IndexOutOfBounds` exception.

You could use Steves approach or use Linq-To-Dataset  which is more readable and powerful:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> rows = searchParamsTable.AsEnumerable()
                         .Where(r => r.Field<String>("TABLE") == tableNumbers[i] 
                                 &&  r.Field<String>("FIELD ") == fieldName[i]);
if(rows.Any())
{
    // do something with the rows, for example create a new DataTable from the result:
    DataTable tblSearch = rows.CopyToDataTable();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Supposing your `i` index var is right then you should check if any row is returned from the Select statement

```
DataRow[] rows = searchParamsTable.Select(string.Format("TABLE = {0} AND FIELD = '{1}'", 
                 tableNumbers[i], fieldName[i]));

if(rows.Length > 0)
   rows[0]["VALUE"] = wildcardedSearchString;
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, trying this now.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing quite a lot of array indexing in that statement, so exactly which one that is out of bounds is hard to tell. Are you sure `i` is a valid index into both tableNumbers and fieldName ?

Try breaking the statement up into separate lines, then use the debugger to find out.

Comment: Yes i is valid. It appears to be invalid on this piece: [0]["VALUE"]

Comment: Well then I guess you don't get any rows from the database; and hence you will not have a row 0. You need to handle the case when you get no results.